# How can I create an .mo file for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, mo

I have some `.po` files for Wordpress and i want to create `.mo` files.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 58):

### Linux

In Linux, you can just run this in Terminal:

```
msgcat yourFile.po | msgfmt -o generatedFile.mo -
```

or

```
msgfmt -o generatedFile.mo yourFile.po
```

You can view more information about these commands by typing:

```
man msgcat
man msgfmt
```

### Mac OS X

You can get `msgcat`/`msgfmt` (as above) either with Xcode or with `brew install gettext`.

However, it will not add them to your path to avoid conflict with OS X's own gettext utility (says homebrew). You can either add it anyway by adding this to your `bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin
```

Or otherwise if you only need `msgcat`/`msgfmt` you can use aliases. Just add these lines to your `bash_profile`:

```
msgcat='/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin/msgcat'
msgfmt='/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin/msgfmt'
```

Hope this helps! (Thanks to Georgi Stoyanov!)

### Windows

On windows you can install [MinGW (Minimal GNU for Windows)](http://www.mingw.org/) you need to select mingw32-gettext (bin and dev) durring installation and msgfmt and msgcat exe files will be installed. By default in `c:\MinGW\bin`. In order to use this tools you need to add that directory to your PATH variable. You can do that from command line using:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\MinGW\bin
```

or from Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables.

Comment: No 'msgcat' or 'msgfmt' on Mac OS X Mavericks. Couldn't find it in brew search either. What OS/Terminal am I supposed to run that from ?

Comment: @Norris I am a Linux user. I don't have a Mac to be able to test it, but [this will help you](http://anoved.net/2008/01/msgcat-and-mac-os-x/).

Comment: Author of the "Msgcat and Mac OS X" post here. To clarify, my post was about using the Tcl package `msgcat`, not installing the command line tools discussed here, so it might *not* be much help.

Comment: I was just upset because the answer threw me of when I discovered that it's a Linux specific command. Now that the answer mentions it I'm all right :)

Comment: If someone has a solution for Mac OS X/Windows is free to edit the answer or to leave a comment here.

Comment: I have msgcat/msgfmt on my OS X installation. I think it was bundled with XCode.

Comment: Wow. This was easier! I had the same issue too! `:D`

Comment: If you're on OS X you can get `msgcat`/`msgfmt` with `brew install gettext`. However, it will not add them to your path to avoid conflict with OS X's own gettext utility (says homebrew). You can either add it anyway by adding `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin` to your bash_profile or else if you only need `msgcat`/`msgfmt` anyway you can use alias — add `msgcat='/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin/msgcat'` and `alias msgfmt='/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin/msgfmt'` to your bash_profile. Hope this helps!

Comment: on Windows you can install gettext-devel package in cygwin

Answer (score 6):

If you have opened POedit, then select language in which to translate and click on ok, then it fetch all the items/strings where __ or _e functions were applied to be translated. Just translate them and do these steps like go to catalog select update from sources and then save current catalog. MO file generated/updated successfully.

Regards,
Zubair Khan

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you could run the .po file through a tool like [pocompile](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pocompile). Some editors are a bit more comfortable, for example, [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) can compile .mo files automatically. :)

Comment: Thanks. I have opened poedit but i dont know how it generates me the .mo files. can you giv eme some tipps?

Answer (score 2):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Localization WordPress in Your Language « WordPress Codex  and  http://codex.wordpress.org/Files_For_Direct_Translation Files For Direct Translation « WordPress Codex  and  http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers  I18n for WordPress Developers « WordPress Codex